# Replace a bookmark in a Word document with the contents of another word document

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I'm looking to replace a bookmark in a word document with the entire contents of another word document.  I was hoping to do something along the lines of the following, but appending the xml does not seem to be enough as it does not include pictures.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...

Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(filename);
var bookmark = doc.Bookmarks.OfType<Bookmark>().First();

var doc2 = wordApp.Documents.Add(filename2);

bookmark.Range.InsertXML(doc2.Contents.XML);
```

The second document contains a few images and a few tables of text.

---

**Update**:  Progress made by using XML, but still doesn't satisfy adding pictures as well.

Comment: What does "no such luck" mean?

Comment: "The Range of the bookmark is readonly."  So I do not know how to set the contents.

Comment: what about copy+paste- document content paste into bookmark... this would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've jumped in deep.

If you're using the object model (`bookmark.Range`) and trying to insert a picture  you can use the clipboard or `bookmark.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(...)`. If you're trying to insert a whole document you can copy/paste the second document:

```
 Object objUnit = Word.WdUnits.wdStory;
 wordApp.Selection.EndKey(ref objUnit, ref oMissing);         
 wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdPasteDefault);
```

If you're using XML there may be other problems, such as formatting, images, headers/footers not coming in correctly.

Depending on the task it may be better to use [DocumentBuilder](http://openxmldeveloper.org/wiki/w/wiki/documentbuilder.aspx) and OpenXML SDK. If you're writing a Word addin you can use the object API, it will likely perform the same, if you're processing documents without Word go with OpenXML SDK and DocumentBuilder. The issue with DocumentBuilder is if it doesn't work there aren't many work-arounds to try. It's open source not the cleanest piece of code if you try troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with openxml SDK and Document builder. To outline here is what you will need

1> Inject insert key in main doc

```
public WmlDocument GetProcessedTemplate(string templatePath, string insertKey)
{
    WmlDocument templateDoc = new WmlDocument(templatePath);
    using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        mem.Write(templateDoc.DocumentByteArray, 0, templateDoc.DocumentByteArray.Length);
        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open([source], true))                            
        {
            XDocument xDoc = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
            XElement bookMarkPara = [get bookmarkPara to replace];
            bookMarkPara.ReplaceWith(new XElement(PtOpenXml.Insert, new XAttribute("Id", insertKey)));
            doc.MainDocumentPart.PutXDocument();
        }
        templateDoc.DocumentByteArray = mem.ToArray();
    }
    return templateDoc;
}
```

2> Use document builder to merge

```
List<Source> documentSources = new List<Source>();
var insertKey = "INSERT_HERE_1";
var processedTemplate = GetProcessedTemplate([docPath], insertKey);  
documentSources.Add(new Source(processedTemplate, true));
documentSources.Add(new Source(new WmlDocument([docToInsertFilePath]), insertKey));
DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(documentSources, [outputFilePath]);
```